# Showing the contents of a MYSQL database on a webpage using node.js and html

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I’m teaching myself how to use HTML and node.js, and right now I’m trying to create a webpage which stores user input in a MYSQL database and then displays the contents of the database to the webpage (I put all of my information in a table called names). I’ve figured out how to insert data into my database, but I’m having problems displaying the information in my database on my webpage.

When I type localhost:3000/ into my browser, I’m able to see the HTML form, but when I check the console on Chrome, there’s an error: 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'

Here’s my index.js file:

```
const express = require("express"); 
const bodyParser = require("body-parser") 
var mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express(); 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true})); 

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '123',
  database: 'info'   
}); 

conn.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected!');   
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {            
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/user.html");
}); 
    
app.post("/insert", function(req, res) {  
    var name = req.body.name;               
    var occupation = req.body.occupation;   
        
    var sql = 'INSERT INTO names values(?,?)';
    conn.query(sql,[name,occupation],function (err, data) { 
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send("Data inserted.");
    });    
}); 

app.get('/display', (req, res) => {

  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM names';
  conn.query(sql, function(err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(result);
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function(){ 
    console.log("Running on port 3000"); 
})
```

Here’s my user.html file:

```
<html>

<body>

<h2>Names</h2>

<p id="names"></p>

<script>

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("names").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/display", true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>

<form action="/insert" method="POST">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="" name="name">
    <label>Occupation</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="" name="occupation">
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm extremely new to this, and although I’ve looked at a lot of the posts about this problem on SO, I haven’t been able to figure this out. Could someone help me with solving this issue? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you swapped out the /display endpoint to just return dummy data (don't do a db request). Do you get the same error? If so, maybe this issue is not related to databases at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I ended up figuring it out — I should have been putting localhost:3000 in my xmlhttp.open() call.